# Excluding files while deploying to Artifactory using Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, artifactory

We are working with Maven 3.3.9 version, and deploying to v using Maven. where we added distribution management within pom.xml  and running Maven goal "mvn clean deploy". Till now everything is working fine and all the files like .pom,.jar,.xml etc are deploying to Artifactory.

Now, we got a scenario where we want to deploy only jar file and exclude all other files while deploying using Maven.

I have tried as mentioned here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html by using

`mvn deploy -Dtypes=jar` but no luck.

How to exclude files while deploying to artifactory using Maven?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What is the purpose of this approache?

Comment: My developer team just need that Jar file and dont need other files which was getting uploaded with default @khmarbaise

Comment: @Ivan 's answer below is correct. I would also consider using JFrog CLI for maven (as well as Gradle and npm) builds to allow for even greater flexibility with your deployed and resolved artifacts. see CLI documentation here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using maven-artifactory-plugin to deploy Maven projects to Artifactory. And it has `<excludePatterns>` configuration which allows to suppress deployment of files. The following config will deploy only .war file and not .pom

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>build-info</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>publish</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <publisher>
                <contextUrl>https://artifactory.your.company.com/artifactory</contextUrl>
                <username>${artifactory.user}</username>
                <excludePatterns>*.pom</excludePatterns>
                <password>${artifactory.key}</password>
                <repoKey>release-repo</repoKey>
                <snapshotRepoKey>snapshot-repo</snapshotRepoKey>
              </publisher>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```